# Is there a way to keep track of modified dictionary items in python?

Tags: python

I have a GUI that reads in a JSON file and creates a different widget for each element in the JSON that contains the keyword "IMPORTANT".  The other items in the JSON are still important for the program, just not important for the user.  After the file has been read in, the user can add more widgets or modify existing widgets.  It is important that the ordering of the widgets stay the same and that the other items in the JSON stay where they are as well.  For example:

IMPORTANT1 IMPORTANT2 not important IMPORTANT3

might become:

IMPORTANT1 IMPORTANT2 not important USER-ADDED IMPORTANT3

Is there an easy way to keep track of what item the "not important" item in the JSON comes after? I've thought of using a copy of the original JSON, but since users can modify the widgets  which in turn modify the JSON items, it makes it hard to keep track of what item started out as what item.  I had also thought of adding another key to the JSON item, but because of what the JSON is used for, that is not possible.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a separate copy of the json item immediately after you read it in, to compare against.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question]( https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You're asking for whole-program, generic design help.  This is an issue in problem analysis, not a Stack Overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a unique id the the items that just isn't displayed to the user, then later you'd be able to keep track of the items independent of changes made to them. If this is not an option, you could also try looking up the items by a hash value.

For example, if you know that all the items in the list aren't exactly identical, and that their contents won't change due to user editing, you could do something like `tuple(i for i in important_widget.items())` to get an immutable (and therefore hashable) version of your widget to compare to what you had before user editing.

Example

```
data = {
    "some_value_buried_in_the_json": [
        {
            "is_important": True,
            "some_unique_data": 123,
            "user_cares_about": True
        },
        {
            "is_important": True,
            "some_unique_data": 999,
            "user_cares_about": True
        },
        {
            "is_important": True,
            "some_unique_data": 734,
            "user_cares_about": False
        },
        {
            "is_important": True,
            "some_unique_data": 678,
            "user_cares_about": True
        }
    ]
}

pre_unimportant_to_user_data = data['some_value_buried_in_the_json'][1]

# Simulate data being modified by user
data['some_value_buried_in_the_json'].insert(2, {'is_important': True, 'some_unique_data': 111, 'user_cares_about': True})

hashed_value = tuple(i for i in pre_unimportant_to_user_data.items())

for value in data['some_value_buried_in_the_json']:

    if tuple(i for i in value.items()) == hashed_value:

        print('found the previous entry')
```

Running

```
$ python example.py 
found the previous entry
```